# SQL, retrieving only entries that all the IDs of its many-to-many relation are in an array

Tags: sql, hana

need some help with a SQL query. Below I wrote an example of what I want:

I need to retrieve entries that the user has privileges to see all of its components.

The privileges are stored in an **array**, for example, I'm a user with the following privileges: [1,2,3]

In the database, I have a table with the following entries:

| entry_id | entry_name | other_info |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "Example A" | ... |
| 2 | "Example B" | ... |
| 3 | "Example C" | ... |

And I have a many-to-many relationship with the components, meaning which components each entry uses:

| entry_id | component_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 |

I would like to retrieve only entries 2 and 3 for my user, because it's the ones I have access to all of its components. Entry 1 would not be retrieved, since I don't have component 4 in my privileges array.

Example of the desired output:

| entry_id | entry_name |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | "Example B" |
| 3 | "Example C" |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, establish a query of all the entry_id's that have records where your user does not have permission. Then use that in your where clause on your query.

```
--here is a list of entry_id's where components exist that your user 
--does not have permission to
SELECT DISTINCT entry_id FROM tbl2 WHERE component_id NOT IN (1,2,3)


SELECT entry_id, entry_name
FROM tbl1
WHERE entry_id NOT IN (  SELECT DISTINCT entry_id FROM tbl2 WHERE 
component_id NOT IN (1,2,3)   )
```

If component_id can be NULL you'll want to check for that.